# Writing shapefiles using GeoTools

Tags: java, gis, shapefile, geotools

I am trying to write/edit my shapefile attributes using GeoTools library.

```
File file = new File("U:/xyz.shp");    
Map<String, Serializable> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put( "url", file.toURI().toURL() );

DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore( map );
String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
System.out.println( typeName ); 
FeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource( typeName );

FeatureCollection collection =  source.getFeatures();
FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> results = collection.features();
try {
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature feature = (SimpleFeature) results.next();
        feature.setAttribute("FIELD_NAME","NEW_NAME");
        //FIELD_NAME is the name of the attribute
        //NEW_NAME is the modified value oif the attribute          

    }
} finally {
    results.close();
}
```

This does change the value of the attribute in **SimpleFeature** class object feature but doesnot update it to the actual shapefile.
Can someone tell me where I am going wrong.
Thank You.

Comment: take a look at [geotools](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) , heading `Create a shapefile From a FeatureCollection` . In your code is nothing that writes data to a file, there is only code for reading.

Comment: Thanks I actually realized my mistake just before reading your comment. I used FeatureWriter class to work my way out.